# SharePoint 2013 workflow elevated permissions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I have made a SharePoint 2013 workflow for a list in which users have read permission only. I want to give the user rights to kick off the workflow through the Custom List Action. But i get this error everytime:
"Unfortunately, this site has not been shared with you."
How can i solve this? I have already created the workflow using the following msdn article(creating a workflow with elevated permissions): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822159.aspx. 
But this does not seem to help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

**Had to Update-Wrong Links**

If the user only has read permissions, they will be unable to add items to the list. You weren't very clear on how this workflow kicks off or what it does but my guess would be to provide either a custom permission which allows a user to add items but not edit/delete. See [here](http://www.fewlines4biju.com/2013/04/create-custom-permission-level-in.html) for instructions on how to do this.

or

You could enable anonymous users on the list and allow anonymous users to add items. See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/58dde7f9-0220-4917-8fa4-c94376158269/set-add-item-to-sharepoint-list-available-to-public?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy) for instructions on how to do this.

Your security concerns are going to determine your approach but for what I have read I think either would suffice.

**** You must have Admin rights to perform this ****

Answer (score 0):

In `SharePoint Workflow 2013`, you can use the **APP step** that will allow the workflow to be authorized with its identity as a **Full Control** and ignore the current user permissions.

This is will ensure that the workflow will be executed successfully in case the current user has **no** permissions.

> **Note:** The APP Step will be disabled if you didn't elevate the workflow permission.

For more details check [Workflow was Suspended with Unauthorized HTTP / Elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)